# Durandal default route works, nothing else

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, durandal

I have been wracking my brain and the internet and have not found an answer to this issue.  Setup a site using Hot towelette, upgraded it to durandal 2.0 and all the associated packages.  Followed the guide for upgrading from 1.0 to 2.0 on Durandal's site and have everything working except the routes.  The default route works and the site loads the default page as expected.  However clicking on the navs on the top of the page, the url changes but nothing happens.  The url changes to http://host/#view.  I saw the missing slash after the hash and added the hash to the route to fix that, but still does not change the view.  I've tried many different samples etc. but haven't found what the problem is.

main.js

```
    require.config({
    paths: {
        "text": "../Scripts/text",
        "durandal": "../Scripts/durandal",
        "plugins": "../Scripts/durandal/plugins",
        "transitions": "../Scripts/durandal/transitions",
    }
});

define('jquery', [], function() { return jQuery; });
define('knockout', [], function () { return ko; });

define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'plugins/router', 'services/logger'],
    function (system, app, viewLocator, router, logger) {
        app.title = "Remedy Approvals";

        app.configurePlugins({
            router: true
        })

        // Enable debug message to show in the console 
        system.debug(true);

        app.start().then(function () {
            toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';
            toastr.options.backgroundpositionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';

            router.handleInvalidRoute = function (route, params) {
                logger.logError('No Route Found', route, 'main', true);
            };

        // When finding a viewmodel module, replace the viewmodel string 
        // with view to find it partner view.
        //router.makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels' });
        viewLocator.useConvention();

        // Adapt to touch devices
        //app.adaptToDevice();
        //Show the app by setting the root view model for our application.
        app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
    });
});
```

shell.js:

```
define(['durandal/system', 'plugins/router', 'services/logger'],
function (system, router, logger) {
    var shell = {
        router: router,
        activate: activate 
    };

    return shell;
    function activate() {
        var routes = [
                        { route: ['approvals',''], moduleId: 'approvals', title: 'My Approvals', nav: true, hash: '#/approvals' },
                        { route: 'alternate', moduleId: 'alternate', title: 'Alternate Approvals', nav: true, hash: '#/alternate' }
                ];

        return router.makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels' })
                .map(routes)
                .buildNavigationModel()
                .mapUnknownRoutes('approvals', 'not-found')
                .activate();
    }

//        function log(msg, data, showToast) {
//            logger.log(msg, data, system.getModuleId(shell), showToast);
//      }
    }
)
```

shell.html

```
<div>
    <header>
        <!--ko compose: {view: 'nav'} --><!--/ko-->
    </header>
    <section id="content" class="main container-fluid">
        <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem,
            afterCompose: router.afterCompose,
            transition: 'entrance'} -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </section>
    <footer>
        <!--ko compose: {view: 'footer'} --><!--/ko-->
    </footer>
</div>
```

nav.html

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
        <li role="presentation" data-bind="css: {active: isActive}"><a data-bind="attr: {href: hash}, html: title"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <label class="pull-right">username</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tested this through Chrome debugger and when I click on the nav for the different view, nothing shows up in the console.  No errors, no code, nothing.

Comment: Tried converting the OOB template to Durandal 2.0 and determined the problem i perceived with the hash is not a problem.  Removed the hash: parameter from the routes.  Still does not navigate based on the click of the <a> tag, but if you hit enter with the url in the address from the click, the corresponding view will be displayed.  So the only problem is why the router is not firing on the change of the address.

Comment: It will be a big help if you put your code in jsfiddle

Comment: After doing some research, I discovered that Durandal's main author has joined the Angular core team.  The roadmap is that Durandal will eventually merge into Angular.  Since this is early on in the development process, I will revisit this application in Angular2.  Thank you for looking at the issue.

Comment: It is true that rob joined Angular project but he is already move out to create [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/team.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're using the compose binding on the activeItem property of the router. I don't know if that's "wrong" as such, but I'm using the "router" binding for mine:

```
<div class="container page-host" data-bind="router"></div>
```

Excerpt from http://durandaljs.com/get-started.html:

> At the bottom of the view is a special router binding which connects
>   to our router in the module. This serves as a placeholder where the
>   current "page" will be displayed. The transition property indicates
>   that whenever the page changes, Durandal should use the "entrance"
>   transition animation.